# Nginx ignoring Yii query strings after ampersand

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, 500-error

Im deploying a Yii based application, we are sending query strings via ajax to search for products, on the local apache environment these strings are processed but on our production server running nginx query strings after the '&' are ignored

our query string example is

```
/en_GB/site/products?question1=female&question4=skincare&question5=60
```

When sent we hit a 500 error

```
Error 500
Undefined index: question5
CHttpException
Your request is invalid.
```

Our nginx config consists of

```
    location / {
             try_files $uri $uri/ /index-prod.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
            fastcgi_buffers 256 16k;
            fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
            fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
    }
```

any help

Comment: That respond seems from Yii, you request _/en_GB/site/products?question1=female&question4=skincare&question5=60_  may fall in _location / { }_